# How can you change position of a machine in juju?

Tags: juju

After I have destroyed a machine with the following command:

```
$: juju destroy-machine --force 3
```

in an juju environment.

My question is; is there a way to say to a new node added in Juju to use as id the "3" so that to have an right order of the machines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are unique identifiers; they cannot be changed once allocated.